# Local extrema for $f(x) = |x-1|x^2$

Tags: calculus

> Find the local extreme points for $f(x) = |x-1|x^2$.

So when $x >1$ we have that $f(x) = (x-1)x² = x^3-x^2$

differentiating $f$ we get $f'(x)=3x^2-2x$

and now $f'(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow 3x^2-2x = 0 \Leftrightarrow x(3x-2)=0$ so we have $x=0$ or $x=\frac23$.

Differentiating once more results in $f''(x)=6x-2$ and now evaluating this we get $f''(0) <0$ and $f''(\frac23)>0$ so $x=0$ is a local maximum and  $x=\frac23$ is a local minimum.

And now when $x <0$ we have that $f(x)=-(x-1)x^2 = -x^3+x^2$

and the derivative is $f'(x)=-3x^2+2x$ and it follows that $f'(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow -3x^2+2=0$ so $x=0$ and $x = \frac23$.

Differentiating once more we get $f''(x) = -6x +2$ and from here $f''(0) > 0$ and $f''(\frac23) < 0$ so $x=0$ is a minimum and $x=\frac23$ is a maximum.

So overall conculsion is that the local extrema for $x>1$ is that $x=0$ is a maximum and $x=\frac23$ is a minimum

and for $x < 1$  $x=0$ is a minimum and $x=\frac23$ is a maximum.

Looking at the graph this doesn't seem to be the case. I see that when $x>1$ the minimum occurs at $x=0$ and the maximum at $x=\frac23$ what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that when $x>1$, $x=0$ can be a solution ?

Comment: Mathjax tip: Instead of `\Leftrightarrow` try `\iff`

Answer (score 1):

As

$$|x-1|x^2=\pm(x-1)x^2$$ we have two stationary points where

$$((x-1)x^2)'=(3x-2)x=0$$ (the sign does not matter), i.e. $x=0,x=\dfrac23$.

As they are both $<1$, the relevant second derivative is $2-6x$ and we have a minimum, then a maximum.

But $x=1$ forms an angular point (the derivative ceases to exist) and is also a local minimum because the derivative switches from negative to positive.

Answer (score 0):

You started with $x>1$ and you got $x=0$ or $x=\frac 2 3$ as points where $f'$ is $0$. These points do not satisfy the condition $x>1$. So there are no points with $x>1$ where $f'(x)=0$. This means the function is monotonic on $(1,\infty)$. 
For $x<1$ what you have done is correct. Did you think about $x=1$? Is it a local extremum?

Answer (score 0):

When $x>1$ you cannot accept $x=2/3$ and whatever happens there.
The answer for $x<1$ is that  there is a local min at $x=0$ and local max at $x=2/3$.

When $x>1$ there is no local max/min.

When $x=1$ there is a local min at $x=1$.